# Drawing a line with a 'raised effect' / gradient in Core Graphics & CorePlot

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-graphics, core-plot

I want to apply a 'raised effect' to a line. It will look similar to this:

[image]

At first I thought of using a gradient fill but the standard gradient fill will just apply the gradient in one direction regardless of the direction of the line like this:

[image]

The lines are actually part of a scatter plot drawn using CorePlot but since CorePlot allows you to apply more or less anything you can do in core graphics, core graphics solutions should apply here.

Comment: When you tried it, what method did you use to create the gradient? For example, you can use `CGContextDrawLinearGradient()` and pass in a start and end coordinate. If you did that, you'd need to make the gradient be perpendicular to the line you're currently drawing.

Comment: Thats the method I used yes but it can only be perpendicular to one of the lines shown in the example at a time.

Comment: That's correct. You have to draw each line separately with a different gradient.

Comment: That wont be possible as I can't control the drawing of the lines just the fill, the line is drawn by core plot.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve an acceptable effect with shadows. If that won't work, make several plots. Give each plot the same data points, but vary the line widths and colors to achieve the 3D effect.

Comment: Hmm I would need quite a few plots to achieve a gradient and even then I don't think it would be a smooth gradient.

Comment: Please add an enhancement request to the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

Comment: Added to issue tracker, http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=491&thanks=491&ts=1357224674.